# Adding a new user to firebase database android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

here's my method to add new user to the database I dont know what I am doing wrong

```
//add a new user

public void addNewUser(String email, String username, String description, String website, String profile_photo) {
    User user = new User(email, 1, userID,StringManipulations.condenseUsername(username));
    myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbName_user))
                .child(userID)
                .setValue(user);

    User_account_settings settings = new User_account_settings(description,
                username,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                profile_photo,
                StringManipulations.condenseUsername(username),
                website
     );
    myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbName_user_account_setting))
                .child(userID)
                .setValue(settings);

}
```

Here is firebase database setup for nodes:

[image: click to open image]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: why don't you add a success and a failure listener while setting the listener, may be you are getting some errors. put a log in the failure listener part and post the error log here

Comment: And what is wrong with this code? What are your expectations?

Comment: Is this question about creating a user or storing the user information in your database?

Answer (score 0):

try adding `Firebase.CompletionListener()`  and get your will get the error if something wrong happens and on successful it will show success message.!

```
  //add a new user

public void addNewUser(String email, String username, String description, String website, String profile_photo) {
    User user = new User(email, 1, userID,StringManipulations.condenseUsername(username));
    myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbName_user))
                .child(userID)
                .setValue(user, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
        if (firebaseError != null) {
            System.out.println("Data could not be saved. " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
        }
    }
});

    User_account_settings settings = new User_account_settings(description,
                username,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                profile_photo,
                StringManipulations.condenseUsername(username),
                website
     );
    myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbName_user_account_setting))
                .child(userID)
                .setValue(settings, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
        if (firebaseError != null) {
            System.out.println("Data could not be saved. " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
        }
    }
});

}
```